# Маршрутизация в тунеле ipsec между 2-мя микротиками

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, ipsec

есть два микрота(головной и филиальный) у обоих белые адреса, настроил между ними тунель ipsec, на филиальном микроте дхцп с сеткой 192.168.10.0/24 у головного офиса 192.168.1.0/23 маршруты построил, вижу всех и все, но вопрос в следующем как завернуть весь трафик с филиального на головной, в смысле чтобы филиальный шел во внешний мир через головной маршрутизатор 192.168.1.1

Comment: в гугле не пробовали поискать? по ключевым словам? примерно так наверное будет надо https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Routing_through_remote_network_over_IPsec, вообще можете сделать рекурсивный роутинг, через таблицы маршрутов на дхцп, т.е. выдать адрес с маской 32 на адрес шлюза через филиальную сеть, и дефолтный маршрут на адрес основного шлюза. но на железке универсальнее.

Comment: @yakov не маршрутизируется айписек)

Answer (score 0):

Первое - айписек не маршрутизируется, совсем, никак не маршрутизируется.

Чтоб отправить трафик через другой роутер в политиках  ipsec поставь подсеть 0.0.0.0/0 и добавь  192.168.10.0/24 в политику "не шифровать"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: второе - кто-то говорил про маршрутизацию IPSEC-трафика? если вы не будите шифровать траффик, как же он тогда достигнет внутреннего адреса шлюза на другой стороне. пускать весь траффик в крипто-мап конечно можно попытаться, но вы не объяснили как же тогда различать траффик от самого роутера, и пользовательский, который надо зананить с другой стороны.

Comment: В вопросе ясно описанно что человек хочет маршруты, в вашем комменте тоже про маршруты опять... Нат только на выходе с ван интерфейса. Айписек не натится.. Шлюз - он дешифруется на шлюзе уже.

Comment: Про змею с хвостом - да может проблема, но обычно ике не подвержен этой проблеме.

Comment: я привел ссылку в которой как раз дается развернуто, то что нужно. я просто обратил внимание, что вместо snat с заворачиванием траффика в тоннель на стороне шлюза похожую схему можно организовать прописав маршрут *на клиенте* до шлюза в головном офисе, и затем сделав этот адрес шлюзом по умолчанию *для клиента*. плюс в том что это можно сделать на DHCP-сервере(если я правильно понял то он на центральном микротике настроен) на центральном устройстве не перенастраивая правила на филиальных, минус в том, что может не всегда работать. например когда на клиенте дхцп-клиент не включен.

Comment: дхцп настроен на клиентском микроте, пробывал прописать маршрут с клиентского 10.0/24 на шлюз головного офиса, ссылку смотрел все настроенно также но клиентский светится в миру всеравно как отдельный интерфейс а не как головной, на счет дхцп понял, но вся суть в том чтобы серые сетки были разные.

Comment: @Yakov >> сделать рекурсивный роутинг, << я не против ссылки, просто говорю что роутинга нет

Comment: @Apache забудьте про маршруты - вы делаете айписек... говорю одно - добавил маршруты....

Comment: для начала пусть у вас есть две сети класса C, одна скажем 10.0.0.0/24 в центре, вторая 192.168.0.0/24 в филиале. вам нужно на обоих концах сделать одинаковые правила и выбрать одинаковые трансформсеты, проверить, попинговать с обоих сторон эти адреса, убедиться, что эти подсети у вас не попадают в нат, и не уходят в по дефолтному маршруту, и при попадании траффика в "крипто-мапы" создаются SA и поднимается тоннель. у меня аса с несколькими подсетями + динамическая маршрутизация прекрасно уживается с микротиком на удаленном объекте. между двумя микротиками это проще в разы.

Comment: сложность в вашем случае в том, что вам нужно сделать правила разрешающие нат, но только не в сторону этих "серых" подсетей, причем как на филиале так и в центре. если у вас трафик попадет в нат, он до тоннеля не дойдет, и уйдет в маршрут по умолчанию. вообще вопрос в том а нужно ли вам заворачивать весь траффик в тоннель, нагружая проц  роутера шифрованным трафиком? не выйдет так что у вас скорость будет ниже чем пропускная способность канала провайдера в филиале?

Comment: @Yakov захват айписек перед построутингом

Comment: @eri, я не берусь утверждать в какой момент это делает микротик, но на моей не слишком древней RB960 без правила в srcnat c -j accept с подсетями которые участвуют в тоннеле перед маскарадингом вертолет не летел.

Comment: @Yakov добавил картинку

Comment: Вы правы, после прероутинга

Comment: у меня в ужатом виде правила по минимуму выглядят вот так https://pastebin.com/RLHyZWue 
без правила add action=accept chain=srcnat перед маскарадингом тоннели у меня к асе не поднимались